# Change path of startup.py in QGIS

Tags: qgis, startup.py

We use QGIS in the company on many PCs. For one, many settings are now to be regulated via the startup.py. I am looking for a way that the startup.py no longer has to be stored under the personal folder of the user, i.e. under:
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3

I want that the file can be located on a central network drive and QGIS looks for the startup.py at this location.
I want to set this setting in qgis_global_settings.ini and have tried the following code for this.

I use the qgis version 3.22.16 LTR.

```
[PythonPlugins]
#Path to the Startup.py
PythonPlugins\startup\file=P:\QGIS\8_Update_QGIS\QGIS_Update\QGIS_Config\startup.py
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: you can start qgis from the commandline or from a batchfile with the option: --code path/to/scriptname.py

Comment: i would like to control it via qgis_global_settings.ini, so that the user has to consider as little as possible. During the installation the qgis_global_settings.ini should be placed once in the installation directory and then further settings should be controlled via the central startup.py. A further batch file would make the installation process more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use a [`PYQGIS_STARTUP`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-pyqgis-startup-environment-variable) environment variable pointing to the path of your custom QGIS Python script. It doesn't have to be called `startup.py`, it can be called `anything_you_want.py`.

If you're using a [`QGIS_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_FILE`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#globalsettingsfile) system environment variable to tell QGIS to load a custom qgis_global_settings.ini from a network drive, you can also set a `PYQGIS_STARTUP` system environment variable.

If you're creating a custom qgis_global_settings.ini and storing it in the installation folder on each device that you install QGIS on, then you can set the `PYQGIS_STARTUP` environment variable in the .ini file (in the `[qgis]` section).

```
[qgis]
customEnvVars="overwrite|PYQGIS_STARTUP=/path/to/custom_startup.py"
```

However, if you're using the custom startup.py script to control settings normally configured in qgis_global_settings.ini why not just set them in qgis_global_settings.ini and store that on your network drive? If you're providing custom pyqgis functions in the startup.py, you can then keep settings separate from code.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't quite work for me. I have the startup.py on the following network drive: P/QGIS/8_Update_QGIS/QGIS_Update/QGIS_Config/startup.py and for this I have added the following code to qgis_global_settings.ini:
[qgis]
customEnvVars="overwrite|PYQGIS_STARTUP=P:/QGIS/8_Update_QGIS/QGIS_Update/QGIS_Config/startup.py

Comment: Define "doesn't quite work"? Nothing happens, you get an error, or something else? It works for me with a simple script that logs a message using `QgsMessageLog.logMessage(etc...)` stored on a Windows network drive. Perhaps check your path.

Comment: Nothing happens, so the file is not called when starting qgis

Comment: I can't reproduce. It works for me with any .py script stored locally or on a network drive, either set by a `PYQGIS_STARTUP=some script.py` environment var or  via `customEnvVars="overwrite|PYQGIS_STARTUP=some script.py"` in a .ini file. Perhaps check your .ini file is getting loaded.